# Remote mysql server access

Tags: mysql, xampp, wan

I have a mac computer and I run "xampp" my sql server on it.

It works great locally but I want to access it from lets say my iPhone thats use 3g connection.

I'm using the external ip of my computer but don't get to the sql server.

I opened the 3306 port I'm my router but still doest work...

what should I do? (I'm using mac).

thanks for help

Comment: Try this link (its is for wamp but wamp is the basic xampp for windows): https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/accessing-mysql-or-phpmyadmin-from-outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use port forwarding and forward all traffic to port 3306 to your computer that runs mysql.

http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/